# How do I automatically find a user's location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, language-agnostic, location, detect

I am currently working on a show listing website.  I am going to display show information by location for the user sorted in a variety of different ways.

I **know** I could ask the user where they are located when they first sign into the site, but I've noticed that many sites have this capability built in to detect location automatically (Example, see [Last.fm](http://www.last.fm/) "Events: Concert Listings in your area").

How do they do this?  I'm currently building my website in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote some of the answers you like, and possibly mark an accepted answer. People can always use encouragement.

Comment: i upvoted three answers.  But someone has been down voting everything.

Comment: @Coding: Interesting. Carry on then, good question.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a link to the documentation on the relevant Google Maps API:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation

It shows an example of how to use it:

```
/**
 * Set the currentState_ and currentCountry_ properties based on the client's
 * current location (when available and in the US), or to the defaults.
 */
InTheNews.prototype.setDefaultLocation_ = function() {
  this.currentState_ = this.options_.startingState;
  if (google.loader.ClientLocation &&
      google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code == "US" &&
      google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region) {

    // geo locate was successful and user is in the United States. range
    // check the region so that we can safely use it when selecting a
    // state level polygon overlay
    var state = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region.toUpperCase();
    if (InTheNews.stateNames[state]) {
      this.currentState_ = state;
    }
  }
  this.currentCountry_ = "US";
}
```

And tells you what you will get from it:

> When populated, the
>   `google.loader.ClientLocation` object is
>   populated with the following
>   metro-level granularity properties:
>
> - `ClientLocation.latitude` — supplies the low resolution latitude associated with the client's IP address
> - `ClientLocation.longitude` — supplies the low resolution longitude associated with the client's IP address
> - `ClientLocation.address.city` — supplies the name of the city associated with the client's IP address
> - `ClientLocation.address.country` — supplies the name of the country associated with the client's IP address
> - ClientLocation.address.country_code — supplies the name of the ISO 3166-1 country code associated with the client's IP address
> - ClientLocation.address.region — supplies the country specific region name associated with the client's IP address

Comment: I'm sort of new to the community, so this may be off base, but how does including a snippet from the page materially add to the answer?  He's still going to have to click the link to use the API, isn't he?

Comment: @runako: The idea is for SO to be a wiki full of information. So having the link is a great start, but giving a bunch more information to give someone a good head start is even better.

Comment: @runako - What if the page moves, or gets deleted?

Comment: In that case, the docs posted above are most likely deprecated as well.

Comment: @runako: And then this wiki can be edited. I recommend you read through the FAQ for more info on why we prefer this on SO if you want more info.

Comment: Could you provide a link?  It sounds like the recommendation is to mirror API docs in the wiki here where relevant to a question, but I can't find anything about the expectations around this in the FAQ.  Would definitely be helpful: wiki posting style != Q&A posting style.

Comment: Also -- might want to add something to the FAQ concerning how to handle mirroring docs on official vendor API pages (i.e. developer.apple.com) vs. docs on 3rd party sites (i.e. joesblog.com).  I'd argue that you don't really want to try to mirror a canonical source like the former.

Comment: FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sofaq-official  &&  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sofaq

Answer (score 1):

They usually do using IP resolution by IP tables. 
[ip2nation](http://www.ip2nation.com/) might give some idea

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at [MaxMind's GeoLite](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) soluton for IP location. An open source solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new way, in fact it's the better way to find the geographical location, because the browser will natively support the W3C API for geolocation... You should check out [GeoMereLaal](http://github.com/parolkar/geo_mere_laal).

Answer (score 0):

http://humbuckercode.co.uk/licks/gems/geoip/ is a simple gem using Maxminds free or paid libraries.

Easy yo set up, no schema updates needed.